# How to know which element user selected in web page used javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can used [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) to get selected words.

```
<div id="content">
    <p class="todo">If you don't know, you can <a href="https://google.com">google</a></p>
</div>
<script>
  let selectionObj = null;
  let selectedText = "";
  function getCurrentSelect() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
      selectionObj = window.getSelection();
      selectedText = selectionObj.toString();
      return {
        selectText: selectedText
      }
    }
  }
  window.onload = function (){
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
      // if (selectOb) console.log(getCurrentSelect()===selectOb);
      // selectOb = getCurrentSelect();

      console.log('onmouseup');
      console.log(getCurrentSelect());
    })
  }
</script>
```

if have two or more identical elements.

```
<div id="content">
    <p class="todo">If you don't know, you can <a href="https://google.com">google</a></p>
    <p class="todo">If you don't know, you can <a href="https://google.com">google</a></p>
    <p class="todo">If you don't know, you can <a href="https://google.com">google</a></p>
</div>
```

how to know which element selected?

I want to be able to return an [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object when selecting text.But I don't know what to do.

Comment: `event.target` will be the selected element.

Comment: Your `Selection` can span over several elements, which of these would you want to get then? Usually we look at the [`selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) one, but it's not clear from your description if that's what you want. (Also, do you know there is a [`document.onselectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event) event that *could potentially* suit your needs better than *mouseup*?)

Answer (score 0):

`window.getSelection()` will return a selection object which contains some of the properties that you might be interested in. For example, you can access the parent element of the text you select via `window.getSelection().baseNode.parentElement`. This will return a [parent element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) which you could manipulate with your code furthermore.

In the code below, I will get the parent node of the selected text, and change the color of it (style property) to red. Please find it here:

```
let selectionObj = null;
let selectedText = '';
function getCurrentSelect() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectionObj = window.getSelection();
    selectedText = selectionObj.toString();
    return {
      selectText: selectedText,
      parentElement: selectionObj.baseNode.parentElement,
    };
  }
}
window.onload = function () {
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('onmouseup');
    const { parentElement } = getCurrentSelect(); // this one will give the parent element of the selected text
    parentElement.style.color = 'red'; // we change one of the properties of the parent element
    console.log(getCurrentSelect());
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  let selectionObj = null;
  let selectedText = "";
  
  window.onload = function (){
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
      // if (selectOb) console.log(getCurrentSelect()===selectOb);
      // selectOb = getCurrentSelect();

      console.log('onmouseup');
      console.log(e.target.innerText);
    })
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <p class="todo">If you don't know, you can <a href="https://google.com">google</a></p>
</div>
```